# Ionic transparent header with buttons that disappear the same way as ion-title

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6, ion-header

I'm using ionic 6 and would like for the page header to be completely transparent in a default state (so just to have an empty space at the top of the page) and when I scroll, to show the header with translucent background with ion-title and additional toolbar button. I have added button to header, but it is not hidden like ion-title is by default
I've been struggling for couple of days to do this.

So, to sum up:

- header to be transparent in default state
- buttons added to header to be hidden in default state like ion-title
- header to show along with ion-title and added buttons when I scroll

For now I have this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help. :)

Comment: I have the same issue with  ion-title but only on first page when app load and only on IOS. So i have removed the tag and put the text directly where should be seen.  What os are you testing?

Comment: Hi @stefani-totokotsopoulou I've restricted the app to iOS mode
 `IonicModule.forRoot({mode: 'ios'}),` so yeah, problem is for iOS.
Not sure what exact problem were you facing, but I don't want the title to be seen at first, only when I scroll, which is by default and is ok.